# Автогенерируемые конструкторы и операторы присваивания rvalue

Tags: c++, c++11

Читаю Прата С++ 2015 стр 1072.

В одном абзаце он пишет

> Если вы **не определили конструктор переноса** или операцию
>   присваивания с переносом, компилятор не будет автоматически
>   предоставлять конструктор копирования или операцию присваивания с
>   копированием

, а в другом

> Например, **если определен конструктор переноса**, то конструктор по
>   умолчанию, конструктор копирования и операция присваивания с
>   копированием не предоставляются

Что с ним не так? Он сам себе противоречит, можете объяснить что и как генерируется?

Comment: Тут думаю нет противоречия. Обеих случаех `конструктор копирования и операция присваивания с копированием не предоставляются` и остается только конструктор по умолчанию. И если Вы его определили, он сам не дает. Если Вы не определили, он сам создасть Конструктора по умолчанию.  Думаю так.

Comment: Конструктор по умолчанию создается только когда нет других конструкторов, я Вас не понимаю, что он не дает?

Comment: `Конструктор по умолчанию` создается только если не опледелен конструктор без параметров. Если вы создали конструктор с параметрами, он сам еще создаст конструктор без параметра. (Извините за мой русский)

Comment: Вы, наверное, что то путаете. Если есть конструктор с параметрами -  конструктор без параметров не создается компилятором автоматически.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<s>ИМХО ошибка перевода.</s> Из оригинала с моим переводом:

**Конструктор по умолчанию:** те же правила, что и в C++98. Генерируется только если класс не содержит определенных пользователем конструкторов.

**Деструктор:** практически те же правила, что и в C++98; единственное отличие - в том, что по умолчанию деструкторы объявляются как `noexcept`. Как и в C++98, виртуальный если деструктор базового класса также виртуальный.

**Копирующий конструктор:** то же поведение, что и в C++98: вызов копирующего конструктора для всех нестатических членов. Генерируется только если в классе нет определенного пользователем копирующего конструктора. Удаляется, если класс определяет операцию перемещения. Генерация этой функции в классе с определенным пользователем копирующим оператором присваивания или деструктором считается устаревшей (deprecated).

**Копирующее присваивание:** то же поведение, что и в C++98: копирующее присваивание всех нестатических членов. Генерируется только если в классе нет определенного пользователем копирующего присваивания. Удаляется, если в классе присутствует определенная пользователем операция перемещения. Генерация в случае, если в классе есть определенный пользователем копирующий конструктор или деструктор, считается устаревшей (deprecated).

**Перемещающий конструктор** и **перемещающее присваивание:** перемещают нестатические члены (соответственно конструктором или присваиванием - прим. АА). Генерируются только если класс не содержит определенных пользователем операций копирования, перемещения, или деструкторов.

*Примечание:* шаблонные методы не участвуют в этих правилах, то есть не предотвращают генерацию специальных функций, даже если их специализации могут иметь подходящую форму (переформулировал - АА).

UPD: только это, кажется, из другой книги - [Effective Modern C++](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1491903996).

Comment: "Генерация этой функции в классе с определенным пользователем копирующим **оператором присваивания** или **деструктором** считается устаревшей (deprecated)." А почему так?

Comment: @uskabuska это так называемое "правило трех": если вы определили копирующий конструктор, копирующее присваивание или деструктор, вам стоит определить все три. Причина - в том, что нужда в переопределении этих вещей обычно возникает из-за того, что класс управляет каким-то ресурсом по парадигме RAII, что требует особой осторожности при копировании и деинициализации. В общем, советую почитать Effective Modern C++, хотя бы чтобы проникнуться количеством подводных камней r-value-ссылок :)

Comment: @uskabuska на чисто механическом уровне: если пользователь определил деструктор, причем не через `= default` - значит не генерируем. Причина - опять же в ресурсах: если вам нужен специальный код для деинициализации, то скорее всего вы также захотите использовать специальный код при перемещении.

Comment: Вот еще нашел хорошую статью, вдруг кому будет интересно. [ссылка](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dn457344.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Думаю нашел что Вы хотели с примером.

If a class has no explicitly defined constructors, the compiler will implicitly declare and define a default constructor for it. This implicitly defined default constructor is equivalent to an explicitly defined one with an empty body. For example:

```
class MyClass
{
    int x;  // no constructor, so the compiler produces an (implicit) default constructor
};

int main()
{
    MyClass m;   // no error at runtime: the (implicit) default constructor is called
}
```

If constructors are explicitly defined for a class, but they are all non-default, the compiler will not implicitly define a default constructor, leading to a situation where the class does not have a default constructor. This is the reason for a typical error, demonstrated by the following example.

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass (int y);  // declaration a non-default constructor

private:
    int x;
};

MyClass :: MyClass (int y)
{
    x = y;
}

int main()
{
    MyClass m(100);     // the non-default constructor is called
    MyClass * p;        // for pointer declarations, the compiler does not need to know about constructors
    p = new MyClass();  // error at compilation: no default constructor
    return 0;
}
```

Since neither the programmer nor the compiler has defined a default constructor, the creation of the objected pointed to by p leads to an error.

Вы были правы. Если нет Конструктора по умолчанию. Он не создается и дает ошибку при использовании.

А Выражение `"Если вы не определили конструктор переноса или операцию присваивания с переносом, компилятор не будет автоматически предоставлять конструктор копирования или операцию присваивания с копированием",` говорит что не будут созданы конструкторы копирования и присваивания. Значит создатся конструктор по умолчанию.

от http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Default_constructor

Comment: Почему Ваш ответ, более чем наполовину, состоит из английского текста?

Comment: Saidolim Djuraev, речь шла об другом :c , но все равно спасибо.