# Неявно определенные и удаленные специальные члены класса

Tags: c++, c++11

Вопрос из ответа на этот [вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/428938/%D0%90%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B-%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-rvalue).

> Копирующее присваивание не генерируется если есть операция
> перемещения.

Операция перемещения? Какая? Конструктор перемещения или перемещающее присваивание? Подобных моментов в том ответе несколько.

И допустим у нас "операция перемещения" объявлена, но мы сделали ее приватной. Копирующее присваивание не генерируется. А что если мы сделаем, вместо приватной, delete (c++11)?

Сколько минимально методов нужно объявить delete что бы запретить любые присваивания/копирования? 4?

Comment: В последнем абзаце не поняно что значит "объявить delete"?

Comment: В c++11 добавили возможность запретить генерацию функции, если нужно. Раньше их помечали приватными для этого.

Comment: Спасибо, что-то я это пропустил.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Достаточно две: конструктор копирования и копирующий оператор присваивания. Если нужно разрешить отдельно перемещение, нужно перемещающий конструктор и перемещающий оператор присваивания либо определить либо объявить как `default`.

В данном случае не проходят следующие условия для конструктора (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor):

- there are no user-declared copy constructors
- there are no user-declared copy assignment operators

А для перемещающего оператора присваивания (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_assignment):

- there are no user-declared copy constructors
- there are no user-declared copy assignment operators

Т.е. хоть и просто удалили, но всё же задекларировали. Так что всё честно.

Ну и на десерт про конструктор копирования и копирующий оператор присваивания:

- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_assignment
- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor

Comment: Функция с delete = декларация?

Comment: @Abyx а где на cppreference пишут что удаленные функции это декларация?