# Qt использование cell и qtablewidget в разных классах

Tags: c++, qt

Самостоятельно изучаю qt, не кидайтесь тапками, пожалуйста. 
У меня есть класс клеток поля, в котором лежит **QTableWidgetItem *item;**

```
            #ifndef CELL_H
            #define CELL_H

            #include <QTableWidget>

            class cell : public QTableWidget
            {
                Q_OBJECT
            public:
                explicit cell(QTableWidget *parent = 0);

                void set_state(int state);
                int get_state();
                void set_fate(int fate);
                int get_fate();
                void preset_neighbours();

                QTableWidgetItem *item;

            protected:
                int state=0,fate=0,neighbours=0;

            signals:

            public slots:
            };
```

И есть класc главного окна приложения, в котором находится QTableWidget.
Как сделать так, чтобы я смог сделать следующую операцию

```
            ui->tablewidget->setitem(x,y,cel.item);
```

Где cel - объект класса cell. На текущий момент программа выдает ошибку:

D:\soft\qt570\Tools\mingw530_32\i686-w64-mingw32\include\c++\ext\new_allocator.h:120: error: use of deleted function 'cell::cell(const cell&)'
         { ::new((void *)__p) _Up(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
           ^

Comment: Хотя бы так: `ui->tablewidget->setitem(x,y, new cel().item);`. Но лучше вынести в отдельную переменную

Comment: Есть подозрение, что у вас перепутана иерархия. Cell это ячейка, а вы почему-то наследуете ее от `QTableWidget`

Comment: @gil9red, это собственный класс. унаследовал от qtablewidget, потому что иначе не получалось объявить QTableWidgetItem *item

Comment: @АндрейЛобанович, промахнулись с комментарием :) `потому что иначе не получалось объявить QTableWidgetItem *item` странные слова говорите, а что мешало? Была ошибка компиляции?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибку выдает не ваша программа, а компилятор! Он сообщает вам что вы пытаетесь, дословно: *использовать удаленную функцию `cell::cell(const cell&)`*. В переводе на человеческий это означает, что где-то происходит вызов конструктора копирования (`cell(const cell&)`), который в классе `cell` не определен (удален на языке компилятора).

Более интересно почему компилятор нзывает конструктор копирования удаленным. Дело в том, что у вас здесь сработали правила генерации и удаления конструкторов и операторов по умолчанию. Эти правила не простые и действительно легко запутаться, [они уже тут обсуждались](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/428938/180450).