# Вопрос про конструкторы классов

Tags: c++, ооп

Вот у меня есть класс:

```
class Cube
{
public:
    int x, y, size;

    Cube(int x, int y, int size) : x(x), y(y), size(size) {}
    QRectF getRect(){
        return QRectF(x, y, size, size);
    }
};
```

И я хочу поместить его в контейнер:

```
QVector<Cube> v;
v.push_back(Cube(1, 1, 1));
```

И получаю ошибку:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'Cube::Cube()'
             new (from++) T();
             ^
```

Чем она вызвана и как её исправить?

Comment: Какой используется компилятор и какая версия стандарта языка С++?

Comment: @AnT MinGW 32bit, C++11

Comment: Тут подробнее https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/428938/180450

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас не определен конструктор по умолчанию. У вас есть

```
Cube(int x, int y, int size) : x(x), y(y), size(size) {}
```

но нет такого

```
Cube() {}
```

вообще лучше записать что-то вроде:

```
Cube(int x = 0, int y = 0, int size = 0) : x(x), y(y), size(size) {}
```

Comment: А разве конструктор по умолчанию обязательно самому определять? Теперь-то работает, но я не совсем понимаю, почему он сам его неявно не определил

Comment: Конструктор без аргументов создается если никаких конструкторов больше нету. Раз у вас есть конструктор, то компилятор не создает дополнительный, чисты конструктор без аргументов.

Comment: Хорошо, а конструктор по умолчанию должен быть всегда? И на каком этапе идёт вызов конструктора по умолчанию, потому что я его вызываю только единожды и с параметрами?

Comment: Дело в том, что, как пишет в тексте ошибки, контейнер выделяет память под ваш класс, поэтому он нуждается в конструкторе без аргументов.

Comment: @Мишаков Максим, я не сразу заметил: у вас же  QVector, а не std::vector, а    QVector::push_back требует конструктор по умолчанию

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Ваше "лучше что-то вроде" зависит от задачи, зачем даете вредные советы?

Comment: @Cerbo а чем это вредно? Это анологично конструктору без аргументов при котором переменным присваивается значение по умолчанию. Один конструктор вместо двух. Ну а если нужны по умолчанию другие значения - впишите нужные. Или по-вашему лучше чтобы там мусор был?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch По-моему лучше когда все решения обоснованы логикой задачи. По-вашему же получается, что якобы есть какие-то "хорошие везде" решения. Совсем не очевидно что по-умолчанию нужно нулями поля инициализировать.

Comment: @Cerbo ну так и не обязательно нулями: можешь ставить любую цифру, которая тебе понадобится: 1, 2, 3, 1456890 - кто запрещает? А по вашему получается, что при вызове конструктора без аргументов что там должно лежать? Мусор? Нет, могут там, конечно, быть специальные рандомно сгенерериванные значения - но я что-то сомневаюсь, что такой конструктор нужен, раз автору ОП он и до этого был не нужен. Так я опять повторюсь: чем этот совет вреден?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Вреден тем, что вы утверждаете что существуют "бест практикс" по-умолчанию. Но, судя по вашим коментариям, сейчас я вижу что вы в них верите, поэтому и не понимаете о чем я вам толкую. Минус вам от меня.

Comment: @Cerbo Ну вот скажите мне, пожалуйста: как вы видите решение выше описанной проблемы? Код не работает, если не определен конструктор без аргументов - это факт! Вопрошающий уже писал, о том, что все заработало, когда он его добавил. Значит: он сдесь нужен. Так по вашему: как он должен его определить? Просто пустым, чтобы там лежал мусор? Так по вашему? Ответьте пожалуйста! Критиковать вы горазды, а вот решение, почему-то не предлогаете.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Так как необходимо для решения задачи. То есть я не знаю и вы тоже, но почему-то уверены что знаете. ТС о задаче ничего не писал, поэтому никаких выводом здесь делать нельзя... Я б не стал придераться, просто видно что ТС зеленый совсем, он теперь будет думать, что всегда надо делать как вы написали, это ж "лучше".

Comment: @Cerbo Для тех, кто в танке: смотрите внимательно вопрос и первый коментарий под моим ответом. Я бы это делал до того, чем писать подобную ерунду, о том, как: "ТС о задаче ничего не писал, поэтому никаких выводом здесь делать нельзя". Так я повторюсь: что вы предлагаете? А на то, что: "всегда надо делать как вы написали, это ж "лучше"" - я не говорил, что так нужно делать всегда, а говорил о проблеме неопределенного конструктора и что лучше просто присвоить значения по умолчанию, чтобы не иметь пустого конструктора, который будет создавать объекты с мусором.

Comment: @Cerbo А вот вашего предложения я так и не услышал. Что, критиковать горазды, а как что-то предложить, так и сдулся?